I am using vue.js for frontend.In that I need to do geocoding and reverse geocoding
I am using vue.js for frontend.In that I need to do geocoding and reverse geocoding.I can't pay for external API.Whether leaflet and its plugin will be a right option or any other library is available?In reverse Geocoding I need to find the city too
I need library for geocoding and reverse geocoding in vue.js

You should consider using OpenStreetMaps/Nominatim. It is a free API that will let you geocode. Here is a link: https://nominatim.org/
